# How to use a CT to measure overcurrent?

Tags: current-measurement, operational-amplifier

I plan to use a CT to measure the current on a resistor whose voltage will be controlled by two SCRs in antiparallel.

The main function of the CT is to detect an overcurrent in the system to proceed to turn off the control over the SRCs.

I am thinking of using two internal comparators of an MCU. These comparators are useful to evaluate that the current doesn't exceed an established maximum and minimum.

In the following figure I1 is the current of the secondary and with the help of R3 it generates a voltage. While the current is within a range, the outputs of the comparators will remain at 0 volts.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftTP0q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Vmax and Vmin are obtained with voltage dividers.

Is there a better way to do this?

Any comments or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Improve the stability of Vref (the point between the two 10k resistors), for example including a capacitor to ground. A voltage follower amp. op. after the voltage divider, helps. 
Alternatively, improve the PSRR using an Zener diode in that point instead.

Comment: After  switching ON, the transformer will give poor indications until a few cycles pass (because of remanent magnetism).   It will also misbehave if the SCRs cause a DC bias current on the input.   Take care!

Comment: And a way to detect over currents in the load?

Answer (score 1):

Your basic idea is OK but a few concerns come to mind.

- The trip points for this circuit will be set > +peak and < -peak. That means that the over-current condition may not be detected until close to mid-point of the cycle.
- The SCRs will remain on until the end of the half-cycle. You have no way to give an instantaneous shut-off. The SCRs or the rest of the circuit may be damaged as a result.
- You have no protection yet on the comparator inputs for a major over-current, transient or surge.
- The 2.5 V reference should be stabilised. Add some capacitance there.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for write.

Regarding "The trip points ... etc", the load is resistive, for example suppose that the resistance for some reason is a short circuit (0 Ohms), the moment that the SCRs turn on, the current will grow rapidly producing a positive pulse to the output of the internal comparator of the MCU which will produce an interruption in the CPU, I think it is not necessary to wait for the half cycle to detect the over current. The detection time of the overcurrent will depend on the response speed of the elements and the firmware of the MCU.

Comment: Regarding "The SCRs will remain on until ... etc", I didn't mention it but the MCU controls a main relay that would disconnect the main power of the system.

Comment: You are correct that a short circuit will result in over-current very soon in the half-cycle. It is most unlikely that you can switch off the relay in under two or three half-cycles. Adding a snubber to the coil will delay it further. You *can* switch off the SCR, as mentioned in the answer, but not until the end of the present half-cycle.